# How to reset dictionary on each iteration of for loop

Tags: python-3.x, file, class, dictionary, self

Below is my code to open each file in a directory and find the number of class,function, characters, and lines. When I print the output the dictionary values add up, how do I avoid this?

```
import os
class FileAnalyzer:
    
    def __init__(self, directory: str) -> None:
       
        self.directory: str = directory # NOT mandatory!
        self.files_summary: Dict[str, Dict[str, int]] = dict() 
        self.cnt=0
        self.c=0
        self.cc=0
        self.ct=0
        self.analyze_files() # summerize the python files data

    def analyze_files(self) -> None:
        
        
        for filename in os.listdir(self.directory):
            if filename.endswith(".py"):
                with open(os.path.join(self.directory, filename), 'r') as f:
                    
                    for line in f:
                        
                        self.c+=1
                        line = line.lstrip()    
                        if line.startswith("class "):
                            self.cnt+=1
                        
                        if line.startswith("def "):
                            self.ct+=1
                        # Move to the start of file
                        for i in line:
                            if not line.startswith(" "):
                                self.cc+=1
                        self.files_summary[filename] = {"class":self.cnt,"function":self.ct,"line":self.c,"char":self.cc}                    
                for k,v in self.files_summary.items():
                    print (k,v)
```

Below are the two input files I am using:

file1.py:

```
definitely not function

This is def not a function def
```

file2.py:

```
"""
    This file has:
        - 2 classes
        - 4 functions
        - 25 lines
        - 270 characters
"""

def func1():
    pass

def func2():
    pass

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output I get is:

```
file1.py {'class': 0, 'function': 0, 'line': 3, 'char': 56}
file1.py {'class': 0, 'function': 0, 'line': 3, 'char': 56}
file2.py {'class': 2, 'function': 4, 'line': 28, 'char': 275}
```

Expected output:

```
file1.py {'class': 0, 'function': 0, 'line': 3, 'char': 56}
file2.py {'class': 2, 'function': 4, 'line': 25, 'char': 219}
```

I get repetition of file1 and also the counts are added when looping over the second file.

Comment: You can make life a bit easier and robust here by using the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
    def analyze_files(self) -> None:
        for filename in os.listdir(self.directory):
            if filename.endswith(".py"):
                ...
                for k,v in self.files_summary.items():
                    print (k,v)
```

You are printing files summary in every loop. You may want to print files summary after analyzing all files.

```py
    def analyze_files(self) -> None:
        for filename in os.listdir(self.directory):
            if filename.endswith(".py"):
                ...
        for k,v in self.files_summary.items():
            print (k,v)
```

Also, you need to reset `self.cnt`, `self.ct`, `self.c` and `self.cc` after each loop:

```py
        for filename in os.listdir(self.directory):

            if filename.endswith(".py"):
               ...
            self.cnt, self.ct, self.c, self.cc = 0, 0, 0, 0
```